# how to retrieve text from span & p tag in r

Tags: r

I have following link

```
url = "https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/topic/Adani"
```

In above url I want to extract the headline, para below that and date in 3 different columns.

I am able to extract only one news headline and para with following code

```
results_headline <- url2 %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*@id="c_topic_list1_1"]/div[1]/ul/li[4]/div/a/span[1]')

results_para <- url2 %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="c_topic_list1_1"]/div[1]/ul/li[4]/div/a/p')
```

I want to extract all the headlines,paragraph and date on that page. 
How can I do it in R?

Comment: Hi @Neil, I didn't see any response from you for the answers posted on your earlier question. Could you please check that first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once again you can simply use `css` selector to extract the content of it.

```
url2 = "https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/topic/Adani"

titles <- url2 %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes("div > a > span.title") %>% html_text()

dates <- url2 %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes("div > a > span.meta") %>% html_text()

desc <- url2 %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes("div > a > p") %>% html_text()

data.frame(titles,dates,desc)
```

output:

```
> data.frame(titles,dates,desc)
                                                            titles  dates
1                     \nDRI drops Adani Group overvaluation case\n Oct 28
2            \nAdani Enterprises to demerge renewable energy biz\n  Oct 7
3               \nAdani Enterprises' Q2 PAT falls 6% to Rs 59 cr\n Nov 13
4 \nAdani firm close to finalising RInfra power acquisition deal\n Nov 12
5                            \nAdani group shares surge up to 9%\n Aug 28
6 \nAdani Transmission acquires RInfra WRSSS assets for Rs 1k cr\n  Nov 1
7      \nVedanta, Adani may bid for Bunder diamond project in MP\n Oct 27
8           \nAdani Power coercing land from farmers: M K Stalin\n Oct 31
9                 \nAdani Transmission acquires 2 SPVs from RVPN\n  Aug 6
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    desc
1                                                                                                                                                        Additional director general, DRI (adjudication), K V S Singh, has dropped all charges and summarily closed all proceedings in a speaking order.
2                                                                                                  New Delhi, Oct 7 () Adani Enterprises today announced plans to demerge its renewable energy business into associate company Adani Green Energy Ltd as part of simplifying overall business structure.
3                                                        New Delhi, Nov 13 () Adani Enterprises, the flagship firm of Adani group, today said its profit after tax fell by 6.34 per cent to Rs 59 crore in the July-September quarter of 2017-18 compared to Rs 63 crore in the same quarter a year ago.
4                                      New Delhi, Nov 12 () Adani Transmission is likely to clinch a deal of Rs 13,000-14,000 crore with Reliance Infrastructure to acquire the latter's Mumbai power business much before the January 2018 deadline to mark its foray into power distribution business.
5                  New Delhi, Aug 28 () Shares of Adani group of companies surged up to 9 per cent today as the mining giant will start work on its 16.5 billion dollar Carmichael coal project in Australia in October and is expected to ship the first consignment in March 2020. The stock jumped 9.
6                                                       New Delhi, Nov 1 () Adani Transmission today said it has completed acquisition of operational transmission assets of WRSS Schemes of Reliance Infra for Rs 1,000 crore. In effect, its power-wheeling network crossed the 8,500 circuit km mark.
7 New Delhi, Oct 27 () Metals and mining major Vedanta Ltd and the Adani Group may bid for the Bunder diamond project in Madhya Pradesh from which global giant Rio Tinto exited this year, according to sources. "Vedanta may bid for the Bunder project," said a source on the condition of anonymity.
8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
9
```

Comment: How can I extract date in different column?

Comment: Check the updated answer with different date column.